# Slowdown digestion for a 30 hour journey?

Tags: food, personal-care, bathroom, medicine

I have a long flight journey, followed and preceded by lengthy bus journeys ahead and would like to have a stable stomach and intestines until I reach my destination home. I do not like public toilets, so really want to avoid the airport or the airplane ones. Of course I am not talking about urinals. I am not eating anything before and during the journey. I would like to know if there are any medicines to help in this situation? Additionally, what types of food digest slow, I could have them for my last meal?

Comment: Great answer on The Great Outdoors SE: [Possible diet to avoid/delay defecation](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/11478).

Comment: @DanielStorm If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Comment: Whoever down voted would ever care to post the reason?

Comment: Also you may try and see if there is any NASA or other public research on low bulking foods that were used by the early astronauts that did not have any alternative to diapers if they had to go in the small capsules.

Answer (score 1):

You can eat one or two spoons of minced, not prepared coffee. It will prevent you from going to toilet for some time (few hours or even a day, depends). I tested it and it works. You can eat it with sugar if you do not like the taste.

I also heard that if you eat chocolate for cooking that will do the same but did not tested it.

Anyway make sure you go to toilet before trip. Good luck! :)

Comment: I will try this and comment back in a couple of days. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Add salt if it is too bitter!

Comment: Generally, caffeine is a laxative -- it stimulates (among other things) activity of the colon.  Regular coffee drinkers are generally well aware that they're most likely to need the bathroom a couple hours after their morning coffee.  I'd expect eating ground coffee to have the same effect as drinking the brew (same caffeine content).

Comment: @Cool_Coder Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Opiates will stop your digestion for awhile  ie: HydroCodone, 
And hyoscyamine. It is made for the expressed purpose of stopping the digestive
process for awhile.Used for IBS, Crohn's, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use of a fast-acting laxative about twelve hours before your journey starts will help empty the colon.  Once this is done, you won't need to "go" for twenty-four or so hours, until your colon is refilled by normal digestion.  Combined with avoiding food during the journey and eating light, low-fiber foods for your last two meals before travel, this is likely to be all you need.